# Cómo modificar mi red neuronal convolucional para que detecte una imagen en vez de clasificarla

Tags: python, tensorflow, redes-neuronales, keras, inteligencia-artificial

Estoy empezando con la Inteligencia Artificial, y he programado una red neuronal convolucional para clasificar imágenes entre dos tipos, perros y gatos, pero mi pregunta es:

**¿Cómo puedo hacer que en vez de diferenciar entre dos tipos, solamente detecte si la imagen que le he pasado es de un gato?**

Quiero decir, si le paso una imagen de una patata o de cualquier cosa que no sea un gato que me diga que no es un gato, y en el caso de que si que sea un gato, que me diga que si que lo es, este es el código actual de la red neuronal que estoy programando:

```
epochs = 20
steps_per_epoch = 1000
altura, longitud = 100, 100
batch_size = 32
steps_validation = 200
filtroConv1 = 32
filtroConv2 = 64
filtroConv1_size = (3,3)
filtroConv2_size = (2,2)
pool_size = (2,2)
tipos_imagen = 2
lr = 0.0005
train_labels = ['gatos', 'perros']
test_labels = ['gatos', 'perros']

cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtroConv1, filtroConv1_size, padding = 'same', input_shape = (altura, longitud, 3), activation = 'relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = pool_size))

cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtroConv2, filtroConv2_size, padding = 'same'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = pool_size))

cnn.add(Flatten())
cnn.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))

cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))
cnn.add(Dense(tipos_imagen, activation = 'softmax'))

cnn.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = lr), metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = cnn.fit(train_images, epochs = epochs, validation_data = test_images)
```

Estoy utilizando tensorflow 2.4 y keras, así como python3, entonces, ¿Cómo podría hacer que me dijese si es un gato o si no lo es, en vez de decirme a cual de los dos tipos se parece más?? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Esta pregunta me ha hecho gracia, para bien, porque me ha recordado a la famosa escena de la serie Silicon Valley. Hot dog, not hot dog https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqTntG1RXSY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que hacer dos cosas:

1. Cambiar el nombre de tus labels: `train_labels = ['gatos', 'N0 gatos']`
2. Añadir imágenes aleatorias a parte de los gatos, es decir, que el resto de las imagenes no sean perros, si no cualquier cosa. Ya que si no estarás detectando perros indirectamente

De esta forma tu red neuronal aprenderá a detectar los gatos y a cualquier otra cosa etiquetarla como NO gato.